# How to get ranks by sorting a list in descending order using scipy.stats.rankdata?

Tags: python, rank, scipy.stats

Having a list of numbers such as `[968, 233, 493, 5, 851, 224, 871, 396, 689, 862]` I would like to get a rank of each of them, where the highest number gets the lowest rank.

By using `scipy.stats.rankdata` I get this `array([10.,  3.,  5.,  1.,  7.,  2.,  9.,  4.,  6.,  8.])`.

The problem is that the ranks are given assuming sorting the list in ascending order. How can I get the ranks assuming descending order of sorting given `rankdata` doesn't take this as a parameter?

Comment: Do you have to use rankdata? or could you use something like numpy argsort instead

Comment: @C Haworth I can use anything, feel free to post the code doing this via `argsort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have to use rankdata you can use numpy argsort.

```
import numpy as np
inds = np.argsort(arr)
ranks = np.empty_like(inds)
ranks[inds] = np.arange(len(arr),0,-1)
```

should give you the results you want.

This works by getting the ordering of the elements of the original array using argsort, and then populating a new array using a descending list of numbers in order.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to multiply each element by (-1):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

a = np.array([968, 233, 493, 5, 851, 224, 871, 396, 689, 862])
scipy.stats.rankdata(-a)
```

It gives:

```
array([ 1.,  8.,  6., 10.,  4.,  9.,  2.,  7.,  5.,  3.])
```